# make bigger joomla modal pop up box in admin area

Tags: joomla, popup, modal-dialog

yes its a joomla question and im sorry to annoy but asking on the joomla forum takes forever or gets ignored.

Im really trying to find where i can modify the iframe modal box to be larger than the default.

When you go into article edit mode and choose to insert an intro image or full article image theres a select input field button. When select is clicked it opens a modal window that is quite small. I wanted to apply a full screen modal to it or at least make it 960x600px as opposed to 800x500px

But the thing is that the select button is generated by an xml file with fields in it.

The xml must be calling a function somewhere that generates the html for that button based on type=media inside the xml file but i cant seem to find where that function or code snippet is.

I just want the modal for selecting an image to be larger, it seems crazy not to make such a thing bigger instead of having horizontal and vertical scroll bars.

the file im referring to in joomla 2.5 for the xml fields:

*line 540 and 572 ( Thats the two instances of intro image and full image )*

**administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml**

That is the file where the image intro and full article image select fields are located.

then this file generates the output of them:

*line 203 ( It does a foreach loop to grab the xml fields )*

**administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/edit.php**

But i cant for the life of me figure out where this part in the html output on the article edit mode in the joomla admin is generated:

```
<div class="button2-left">
<div class="blank">

<a class="modal" title="Select" href="index.php?option=com_media&amp;view=images&amp;tmpl=component&amp;asset=34&amp;author=&amp;fieldid=jform_images_image_intro&amp;folder=news" rel="{handler: 'iframe', size: {x: 800, y: 500}}"> Select</a>

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance
john

Comment: You might be interested in supporting a Joomla version of StackOverflow http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file you are looking for is:

**libraries/joomla/form/fields/media.php**

line 121:

```
. ' rel="{handler: \'iframe\', size: {x: 800, y: 500}}">';
```

Comment: thanks so much Shaz. i treid your answer but it still didnt work. that seems to apply it only to the image button under the wysyiwig.

Comment: darn it, ive tried the cache thing and even in other browsers but no luck. Are you sure it works on the intro image and full image select under Images and links section of your article?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question (my bad), please check the file I give you now.

Answer (score 2):

Since it appears that key details of the accepted answer to the original poster's question occurred via direct communication (based on comments in the first answer), for me it was necessary for me to search around for more information on where to change the sizing of modal windows—especially since it seems that the sizing of various popups are defined in different places.

So, in the hopes that this is helpful to others in similar circumstances, I'm leaving what information I was able to find out about which files have to do with modal behavior, appearance, and configuration.

Here's how the list is organized:

- All the files in which I was able to find modal settings defined (or
  items that seemed closely related to modal appearance and/or
  behavior)
- The line number on which relevant settings/configuration occurs (as
  of 2.5.6)
- Quotes of any nearby text that might provide insight to where/how
  that particular modal is being used (when trying to determine if this
  controls the modal you want to change), or a note of any information
  that seems relevant/helpful

And here's the list itself:

- `\administrator\components\com_contact\elements\contact.php` **: 53**
  “COM_CONTENT_SELECT_A_CONTACT"
- `\administrator\components\com_contact\models\fields\modal\contacts.php` **: 69**
  “COM_CONTACT_CHANGE_CONTACT_BUTTON"
- `\administrator\components\com_content\elements\article.php` **: 55**
  “COM_CONTENT_SELECT_AN_ARTICLE"
- `\administrator\components\com_content\models\fields\modal\article.php` **: 78**
  “COM_CONTENT_CHANGE_ARTICLE"
- `\administrator\components\com_menus\models\fields\menutype.php` **: 71**
- `\administrator\components\com_menus\views\item\tmpl\edit_modules.php` **: 46**
  “COM_MENUS_EDIT_MODULE_SETTINGS"
- `\administrator\components\com_menus\views\menus\tmpl\default.php` **: 113**
  “COM_MENUS_EDIT_MODULE_SETTINGS"
- `\administrator\components\com_modules\models\fields\moduleposition.php` **: 77**
  “COM_MODULES_CHANGE_POSITION_TITLE"
- `\administrator\components\com_newsfeeds\models\fields\modal\newsfeeds.php` **: 81**
  “COM_NEWSFEEDS_CHANGE_FEED_BUTTON"
- `\administrator\modules\mod_multilangstatus\tmpl\default.php` **: 14**
  “MOD_MULTILANGSTATUS"
- `\components\com_content\views\article\tmpl\default_links.php` **: 65**
  “class="content-links"”
- `\components\com_weblinks\views\category\tmpl\default_items.php` **: 110**
- `\libraries\cms\form\field\user.php` **: 94**
  "JLIB_FORM_CHANGE_USER"
- `\libraries\joomla\html\toolbar\button\popup.php` **: 53**
   This
  looks like it may be the php file setting up the base parameters &
  such, which is invoked and built off of everywhere else.
- `\media\system\js\modal-uncompressed.js` **: entire file**
   Contains
  the interactive (client-side) logic for modal usage (note that Joomla
  modal windows are SqueezeBox derived).
- `\media\system\js\modal.js` **: entire file**
  Same content as the file above, just minified.
- `\plugins\user\profile\fields\tos.php` **: 81**
   As far as I can see,
  this seems to be used for displaying terms of service to end
  users—probably if you created your own TOS that your users need to be
  aware of and agree to.

Comment: wow! thanks for doing this! how long did it take you to find all this?

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that it took me a few hours; mostly because I had to figure out exactly _what_ I was looking for, in addition to _where_ it might be. Once I came across a few files where the modal size was defined, I noticed enough of a pattern that I realized I could just do a search for specific text in all the Joomla files and have only a few files (and very specific places in those files) to go through. ...I do wish the Joomla documentation was more newbie friendly. I still don't really understand why things are structured the way they are, or even _how_ the current structure works.

Comment: you're right on all. Thanks again, i will get good use out of this. And im sure others will too.

Comment: Edited original to note two additional file locations (on 2012.11.09):
'\administrator\components\com_menus\models\fields\menutype.php' **: 71**
'\libraries\cms\form\field\user.php' **: 94** "JLIB_FORM_CHANGE_USER"